# Greyed out or disable <a>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page that has submitting request every 5 seconds. how can i disable or greyed out the a href in the setTimeoutFunction before the form submits?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
         // disable <a>
         document.forms.form.submit();
      }, 5000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<section class="wrapper">
    <section class="container">
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </section>

        <form id="form" method="post" action="http://toawebsitepost.com">
            <input type="submit" hidden>
        </form>

        <a class="cancel" href="http://toawebsite.com">Cancel</a>
    </section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Links can not be "disabled" per se, so you will have to implement that yourself - add a click handler, that cancels further processing of the click event, and add a class to format the link differently via your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a special CSS class that will remove default behavior from a link. PLease check the example:

```js
      setTimeout(function () {
         // disable <a>
         document.querySelector('.cancel').classList.add('disabled');
         document.forms.form.submit();
         document.querySelector('.cancel').classList.remove('disabled');
      }, 5000);
```

```css
      .disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
      }
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
    <section class="container">
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </section>

        <form id="form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" hidden>
        </form>

        <a class="cancel" href="http://toawebsite.com">Cancel</a>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: _"that will remove default behavior from a link"_ - no, it won't. Not properly, because the link can still be activated by keyboard navigation.

Comment: It's another point which could be fixed with adding of `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: @alekskorovin is this crossbrowser compatible?

Comment: @alekskorovin it seems working..  also, what if user Click canceled and at the same time it submit? how can i prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

As CBroe pointed out it's no good just setting `pointer-events` to `none` when the anchor can still be accessible by keyboard.

Instead you could add a click listener to the anchor. When the `setTimeout` callback is executed it changes a variable called `isDisabled` to true. If the button is clicked before the time out the handler (in this case) logs a message, otherwise we use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop normal anchor behaviour.

```js
const cancel = document.querySelector('.cancel');

cancel.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

let isDisabled = false;

function handleClick(e) {
  if (isDisabled) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // Normally you would be navigating
    // to a website, but in this example
    // we're just logging a message
    console.log(`Navigating to ${e.target.href}`);
  }
}

setTimeout(function() {
  isDisabled = true;
  cancel.classList.add('disabled');
  document.forms.form.submit();
}, 5000);
```

```css
.disabled { color: #ababab; cursor: not-allowed; }
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <section class="container">
    <section class="content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Description</p>
    </section>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="http://toawebsitepost.com">
      <input type="submit" hidden>
    </form>
    <a class="cancel" href="http://toawebsite.com">Cancel</a>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none` will only work for pointer devices (mouse, tab) - but the link will still be accessible & usable via keyboard navigation.

Comment: Fair points, well made. @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your  tag and use  instead.
Using button:

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <section class="container">
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </section>

        <form id="form" method="post" action="http://toawebsitepost.com">
            <input type="submit" hidden>
        </form>

        <button class="cancel" onclick="navigateToUrl()">Cancel</button>
    </section>
</section>
```

JS:

```
navigateToUrl() {
 window.location.href = "http://toawebsite.com"
}

setTimeout(function () {
    // disable <a>
    const button = document.querySelector('.cancel')[0];
    button.disabled = true; 
   document.forms.form.submit();
 }, 5000);
```

---

Or if you want to stick to `<a>` then add a custom CSS class to it to prevent clicks:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // disable <a>
    const aTag = document.querySelector('.cancel')[0];
    aTag.classList.add('disable');
   document.forms.form.submit();
 }, 5000);
```

CSS:

```
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

Comment: `button` does not have a `href` attribute.

Comment: @CBroe ofcourse. Idea is to help with disablement. Updated code to use a function to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event handler to the anchor that selectively calls `event.preventDefault();`, e.g:

```js
let isDisabled = false;

setTimeout(function () {
  isDisabled = true;

  // set anchor class to make it grey

  form.submit();
}, 5e3);

function onInteraction(event) {
  if(isDisabled) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}


/*[...]*/

<a href="https://website.com" onClick="onInteraction" onKeyUp="onInteraction">
  Cancel
</a>
```

Obviously don't use html attributes for event handlers! It's just for illustration